# Bool class - like Num?

Tags: haskell

I have my own type:

```
data MyType = ...
```

Now, I would like to use value of this type in `if`. Is it possible to implement it ? Of course, at this moment I get error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘MyType’
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard semantics of `if`/`then`/`else` are specific to `Bool`. With GHC, it is possible to change the standard semantics using the [`RebindableSyntax`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax) extension. Quoting from the docs:

> ...the `-XRebindableSyntax` flag causes the following pieces of built-in syntax to refer to whatever is in scope, not the `Prelude` versions:
>
> - Conditionals (e.g. `if e1 then e2 else e3`) means `ifThenElse e1 e2 e3`. However `case` expressions are unaffected.

This is my technical answer to the question as asked.

However, my opinionated answer is that you should not do that. Instead, write a predicate of type `MyType -> Bool`; then use `if predicate myValue then ... else ...`. This explicit way is in my opinion more clear and idiomatic; and as a side benefit is more flexible as well because you can have many different predicates of that type, rather than elevating any single one to special status.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it with `-XRebindableSyntax` (although you should listen to Daniel Wagner and not do this):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
module Test where

import qualified Prelude as P


class Decidable b where
    toBool :: b -> P.Bool

instance Decidable P.Bool where
    toBool = P.id

ifThenElse :: Decidable b => b -> a -> a -> a
ifThenElse b ifTrue ifFalse = case toBool b of
    P.True -> ifTrue
    P.False -> ifFalse

data Test = A | B deriving (P.Eq, P.Show)

instance Decidable Test where
    toBool A = P.True
    toBool B = P.False
```

Then in GHCi:

```
> :l decidable.hs
> :set -XRebindableSyntax
> P.putStrLn (if A then "it worked!" else "it failed!")
it worked!
```

Again, don't do this!  Just go with a simple function, it'll save a lot of headache down the line and won't confuse anyone else reading your code who doesn't realize you've changed how the syntax of the language works.